# Complexity of O(N) when comparing 2 tables

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

I have 2 tables and have to find a matching line in the table with a complexity of *O(N).* I know how to do it with a complexity of *O(N<sup>2</sup>),* however how do I do it with a complexity of *O(N)?*

Comment: what does _marching_ line mean ?

Comment: What makes you believe this is possible (with the vague info you have given us)?

Comment: Do you really mean little o(n) or rather big O(n)?

Comment: I need more detail to help you...

Comment: This is not possible in O(N). Do the tables have any unique ID (primary key)? If they have, then O(NlogN) is possible.

Comment: Also, since you're new, a piece of advice. Don't ask the question and go away. We need clarifications most of the times. If you stay with us, chances are you'll get your answer very quickly.

Comment: If the tables are sorted you can do it O(N).

Comment: When you say "table" do you really mean an array or other in-memory data set? Or do you mean a database table?

Answer (score 1):

If by matching you mean some flavor of equality, stuff all members of the smaller table in a Set, then scan the larger table, looking up each entry in the Set you memoized.

What you're describing sounds vaguely like a JOIN, so just "index" on the data you care about.